# Generate Slack notification for certain files using GIT

Tags: git, notifications, slack, slack-api, githooks

Is there any way to send notifications in Slack when there are commits on certain files?
I am migrating a system but the system being migrated is still evolving. I would like to receive a message from the files I have already migrated that were changed in the previous project, so I can keep my code always up to date.

The stack is Git + GitLab, but I'd like to use Git's own hooks.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably adapt [this](https://github.com/chriseldredge/git-slack-hook) `post-receive` server hook as a local `post-commit` hook with a little modifications.